# Get gateway address in Arduino using ESP8266

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-ide

I need the default gateway IP address for my ESP8266. I know that in LUA you can retrieve it with this code:

```
ip, netmask, gateway = wifi.sta.getip()
print(gateway)
```

But how using Arduino/C++?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `WiFi.gatewayIP().toString()` to get it as string.